# GitAhead: unexpected HTTP status code: 404

Tags: git, gitlab, gitahead

I switched from GitKraken to GitAhead in linux.
My already configured and working repository has a gitlab origin.

I opened the repository in GitAhead and whenever I try to fetch, pull or push I got this error:

```
Unable to {whatever I'm doing} from 'origin' - unexpected HTTP status code: 404
```

If I use the linux terminal, I can fetch, pull and push **the same repository** normally.

I don't know if the problem is GitAhead not asking for credentials.

- I've configured my username and email on general and repository config.
- I've tried to add and remove a gitlab account (using personal access token)

Any ideas?

```
# cat ./.git/config

[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://gitlab.com/c****c/a****3.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[user]
    name = Jorge
    email = j****z@c****c.com
```

---

I've asked this same question on [GitAhead's github](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/issues/395) 2 months ago but it got no attention.

This problem is not present in my Windows machine neither in a teammate's linux machine so it must be a misconfiguration problem or something. It's strange because using git commands in the terminal works perfect

Comment: I made a comment on the bug report.

Comment: @JasonHaslam Thank you! Deleting password in Linux "Password and keys" did the trick. After that, after starting GitAhead, it asked for credentials. What should I do with this question on SO? Delete it or "Answer my own question"?